# Open Chrome browser with python script on ec2 instance

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running this python script to open my chrome browser. I am running my script on an ec2 instance which uses selenium.I have installed selenium and required packages on my instance.This is my script

```
from selenium import webdriver

 # The place we will direct our WebDriver to
url = 'http://www.srcmake.com/'

 # Creating the WebDriver object using the ChromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

 # Directing the driver to the defined url
driver.get(url)
```

but when I run this script I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to chromedriver binary as below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver.exe')
```

Download your chromedriver as per your chrome version from below location :

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html